# SQL - Query column that does not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following query where I am querying ISIN field.

```
SELECT Isin FROM FundPriceDetails
WHERE Isin IN
(
'ES06139009N6'  ,   'MAD',
'GB0002634946'  ,   'LSE',
'SG1L01001701'  ,   'SGX'
)
```

The second column does not exist but I wish to show it against ISIN values without inserting the row in my select query
How do I go about doing it ? A the moment I have only ISIN in my select statement. I need to create a anonymous column that contains the next column

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `join`:

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (SELECT 'ES06139009N6' AS lsin, 'MAD' AS col2 UNION ALL
      SELECT 'GB0002634946', 'LSE' UNION ALL
      SELECT 'SG1L01001701', 'SGX'
     ) x JOIN 
     FundPriceDetails fpd
     ON fpd.lsin = x.lsin;
```